# Powershell to get accounts with passwords older than "$"

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of accounts with passwords that are older than lets say 90 days but something is not working right and I am not sure why.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True' -Properties PasswordLastSet,samaccountname,passwordlastset | Where-Object {$_.PasswordLastSet -gt ($_.PasswordLastSet).adddays(1)} | select Name,samaccountname,passwordlastset
```

This is what i got so far but if I run it as is it returns 0 results. I know there are passwords that are older than one day, mine is one of them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to subtract days, by doing adddays(-90)

Comment: yup, and use todays date instead of password expiration day. Just need to wake up a bit more. Thanks for putting me on the right track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your realization in the comments you should compare the `PasswordLastSet` field to today's date less 90 days as follows:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True' -Properties PasswordLastSet | Where-Object {$_.PasswordLastSet -lt (Get-Date).adddays(-90)} | select Name,SamAccountName,PasswordLastSet
```

Use `-lt` for older passwords, or `-gt` for newer passwords.

Comment: It may be possible to put the password age check into the `-Filter` and avoid the `Where-Object` entirely. The `Properties` may then also be unnecessary (or at least this is suggested by my recollection of things I've done at work [I'm at home now and can't check my code]).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin could be wrong but I believe `PasswordLastSet` needs to be specified.

Comment: I actually tried filter originally but had trouble with it because filter seems to behave as if they're strings.  I'm sure there is a way and I just don't know the syntax but after a few tried I went with what I know works universally.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,if you wana export remove #

```
$DaysAgo=(Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$params = @{
  "filter" = 'Enabled -eq $true -and passwordlastset -lt $DaysAgo'
  "Properties" = "Displayname",
  "passwordlastset",
  "samaccountname"
}
Get-ADUser @params |select displayname,samaccountname,passwordlastset #| export-csv C:\result.csv -nti
```